# Access - How to append military time from one field into another as text?

Tags: datetime, ms-access-2016, calculated-field

I have a field `Time_Start` that is a Date/Time (data type) with the Format of hh:nn:ss i.e. military time.

I need to append this value to the end of the text in another field. It won't work with a Calculated field, based on what I've seen and Googled. One attempt was adding this at the end of the Calculated field: `+Format([Time_Start], "hh:nn:ss")` which gives the error "The expression ... cannot be used in a calculated column."

How can I append the Date/Time value from one field onto another?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try using an ampersand for string concatenation instead of the plus.  So:  & format(

Answer (score 0):

Apply *Format* on that "other value" as well:

```
=Format([OtherDateValue]+[Time_Start], "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss")
```

or, if the value is text:

```
=Format(DateValue([OtherDateValue])+[Time_Start], "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss")
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, thanks for your reply. So even if I enter the calculated value as `=Format([Time_Start], "hh:nn:ss")` I get the same ...cannot be used... error. Were you implying putting this line elsewhere?

Comment: I have the hh:nn:ss showing correctly on a form by setting the Control Source property for that field.

Now the question becomes how would I query this in a report - which time syntax? (Maybe that's too vague, in which case I'll respond later...)